# Ionic App not working in emulated iOS phone

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently working on an Ionic application using Angular Framework (ionic 6.13.1 and Angular 11.2.8)

Everything works fine in the browser and on the physical Android phone, even in safari, but when I try to run the application on an emulated iPhone it just shows me an empty screen and I don't know why.

this is my process:

1. First, I clone my repository to my mac ('couse I'm working in a windows pc)
2. Then, I run npm install to download the node_modules
3. I installed `npm install -g ios-sim` and `npm install ios-deploy` like the ionic docs says [Ionic iOS Development](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios#ios-sim-ios-deploy)
4. Then I run `ionic cordova prepare ios` in the terminal. Here is where I think it fails, becouse for some reason, I have to run the same command three times in a row to make it works.
5. When it finally works, I run `ionic cordova build ios`
6. Then, when I run either `ionic cordova run ios -l --external` or just `ionic cordova run ios` or I open XCode to run the app on an emulated device

When the process is finally ended, the emulator shows up and launch the app. Splash screen shows up as usual, but after that it just show me a white or black screen (dependening the ios theme), but nothing of my code shows up. After 20 or 30 minutes of waiting, the app looks exactly the same.

Here is a screen capture of my problem, as you can see, there is no error in the console, and the screenshot was taken 20 minutes after I press run.

[image]

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "tracking-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "9.0.0",
    "cupertino-pane": "^1.2.61",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {
        "PLAY_CORE_VERSION": "1.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After Many hours of researching I found that the problem is a mediaMatcher addEventListener in a file that makes possible the theme detection.

So I make this repository https://github.com/Chej0/ionic-theme-detection.git

In the file `src/app/core/services/internal/theme.service.ts`  in line 57 you'll see that the problem is in addEventListener.
If I remove that line, the app works correctly.
That service is injected in the app.component.ts, that's why all app is not working.
Unfortunately, this listener is very important in the app, so...
Is there another alternative to listen in real time which mode has the iphone? (also that needs to work in android too)

Comment: Maybe the error is in your Javascript. Open safari on the mac, pull down the “Safari” menu and choose “Preferences”. Click on the “Advanced” tab. Check the box next to “Show Develop menu in menu bar”. Now run your app on simulator, and from safari open Develop menu and inspect your application. Check the console to see if something is wrong

Comment: @saperlipopette thank you, I just publish an update with the safari console

Comment: can you share you `app.component.ts` file code.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I just update the question with the html and ts file

Comment: try to wrap your code inside `platform .ready()` for example: `ngOnInit(){
 initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Your Code Here   
    });
}`

Comment: thank you @NajamUsSaqib I just make a repository. The problem is with one AddEventListener that I have in ThemeService. But I still don't know how to fix it, can you help me? ---> https://github.com/Chej0/ionic-theme-detection.git

Comment: Check this plugin for theme detection: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/theme-detection